# Расположение картинки справа налево

Tags: html, css

Есть класс блок в блоке контенте. Картинки идут сверху вниз . А нужно,чтобы шли справа налево. Чего я хочу добиться,смотреть в скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

```css
.block1  {
 position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height:276px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
top:750px;
width: 60.14%;
margin-left: 19%;
height: 1000px;
background-color:#ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="contentfon">
      <div class="content">
        <p><a   href="#" class="block1"><img src="1 блок.png"></a></p>
        <p><a   href="#" class="block1"><img src="1 блок.png"></a></p>
        <p><a   href="#" class="block1"><img src="1 блок.png"></a></p>
        <p><a   href="#" class="block1"><img src="1 блок.png"></a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.content{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction:row;
}
```

И если у тебя идут тупо ссылки с картинками, я бы не стал в "параграф" это заворачивать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, .Ваш совет учту.